# Factory and Builder patterns (mixing two or more patterns)

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, factory-pattern

I know this question was asked for many times, and it may look like the question is a duplicate, but i tried to understand the posts on SO, Google, GoF and didn't found the answer for me...

I understand the difference between the Factory Method and Builder:
Factory Method - Creates objects that derive from a particular base class, decoupling concrete implementation from client

Builder Method - Hides the complexity of the object creation from client

Now I see example that i found on internet ([Abstract Factory Design Pattern for Dependency Injection](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363653/Programmatic-Dependency-Injection-with-an-Abstract-Factory)), it's about an Abstract Factory, but it doesn't matter for my question. It's just one of many articles that i viewed

```
//Abstract Factory for Dependency Injection
//Factory interface
public interface Module1ServiceFactory {
 ComponentA getComponentA();
 ComponentB getComponentB();
}

//Concrete factory
public class Module1ServiceFactoryImpl {
 private Module1ServiceFactory instance;

 private Module1ServiceFactoryImpl() {}

 public static synchronized Module1ServiceFactory getInstance() {
  if (null == instance) {
   instance = new Module1ServiceFactoryImpl();
  }

return instance;
 }

*** SUBJECT METHOD ***
 public ComponentA getComponentA() {
  ComponentA componentA = new ComponentAImpl();
  ComponentB componentB = getComponentB();
  componentA.setComponentB(componentB);
  return componentA;
 }

 public ComponentB getComponentB() {
  return new ComponentBImpl();
 }
}
```

What I see in that example, ComponentA is a complex type that getComponentA() method used to build it.

1. So why this is called Factory and not Builder??? Or it means that Module1ServiceFactoryImpl  implement Factory **AND** Builder patterns?
2. Is it correct (commonly used) to create classes/objects that implements more than one design pattern in software architecture design?

And sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why this is called Factory and not Builder??? Or it means that
>   Module1ServiceFactoryImpl implement Factory AND Builder patterns?

It's called factory, because it's factory, and only factory

```
*** SUBJECT METHOD ***
 public ComponentA getComponentA() {
  ComponentA componentA = new ComponentAImpl();
  ComponentB componentB = getComponentB();
  componentA.setComponentB(componentB);
  return componentA;
 }

 public ComponentB getComponentB() {
  return new ComponentBImpl();
 }
```

I see no builder here. Sure, this isn't simplest approach, but it's definitely not that complex as it would be, if builder pattern were introduced. This is more like JavaBean-way and using setters on freshly created object. Builder pattern requires creation of object in last step, to make it impossible for creating object to be in state between ready-to-use and not-ready-yet.

> Is it correct (commonly used) to create classes/objects that
>   implements more than one design pattern in software architecture
>   design?

Yes, it's correct and used, sometimes. Not that commonly, because every pattern adds some complexity, and multiple patterns add multiple complexity :) But, of course, you can mix builder with factory (builder needs some parts that are factored), facory with builder (factory encapsulates usage of create objects with builder). Patterns are good in working together. MVC is good sample:

*The GoF (Gang of Four) do not refer to MVC as a design pattern, but rather consider it a "set of classes to build a user interface". In their view, it's actually a variation of three other classical design patterns: the Observer (Pub/Sub), Strategy and Composite patterns. Depending on how MVC has been implemented in a framework, it may also use the Factory and Decorator patterns.*

http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvc-and-mvp-for-javascript-and-backbone-developers/

Answer (score 1):

The Factory Pattern basically hides the instanciation *concrete object* (unlike a constructor) and emphasizes the *interface* of the created object instead.

In constrast the Builder Pattern typically helps implementing a *multi-step building behavior* where some step may also be optional. It emphasizes splitting the object creation into logical units rather than creating it semantically at once, unlike a constructor (or factory method) would.

The following samples might express the difference a little more clearly I hope.

```
public class ComponentABuilder {
  private ComponentB componentB;
  private ComponentC componentC;

  public ComponentABuilder BuildComponentB(ComponentB b) {
    this.componentB = b;
  }

  public ComponentABuilder BuildComponentC(ComponentC c) {
    // Added another ComponentC, since just building B would
    // be pointless
    this.componentC = c;
  }

  public ComponentA Build() {
    // Might also be implemented via setters or whatever, the
    // point is that build now returns an object that is fully
    // built according to the steps the consumer performed via
    // the builder's methods, whereas a Factory Method would
    // do all the stuff by theirself.
    return new ComponentA(this.componentB, this.componentC);
  }
}

// Consumer sticks together his very own ComponentA
// in (usually) multiple steps
ComponentA c = new ComponentABuilder()
  .BuildComponentB(new ComponentBImpl()) // step 1
  .BuildComponentB(new ComponentCImpl()) // step 2
  .Build();

// Factory builds their ComponentA according to their
// own internal application, and getInstance is exposed
// as an "atomic" step to the consumer
ComponentA c2 = new ComponentAFactory().getInstance();
```

The Builder Sample is a rather specific case where it makes sense to apply it. It should, however, be usable for difference applications too.

Comment: Thx for an answer, but it still not explain why Module1ServiceFactoryImpl in my example is not "Builder". As I see, public ComponentA getComponentA() does exactly the same thing as MyBuilder.Build (build the complex object)...

Comment: IMHO `getComponentA` does *not* what a builder does. A builder *exposes multiple steps* to the consumer, whereas a factory may perform but does not expose them. I'll think again how I could express my point more clearly and edit my post.

Comment: @AlexDn Please have another look at the new example, I changed it to reflect your question more closely.

Comment: I understand what you saying, but again it messing up in my mind...you say "A builder exposes multiple steps to the consumer..." - Module1ServiceFactory  does the same (ComponentA getComponentA(), ComponentB getComponentA()), from other side Builder should "hide" complexity, but with many exposed methods it looks more complex. For example class Car: Factory can create car basis, engine, doors, wheels...but only the Builder knows that engine can not be assembled to car before basis exists...so why Builder should expose more than one method?

Comment: I agree it is more complex quite often. **First**, for instance, Joshua Bloch recommends a builder instead of a factory (or constructor) to reduce the number of parameters, see http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/208403883?pgno=2. **Second**, you could let different builder implementations decide what concrete parts to use instead of letting the consumer passing them (like I did). In this case, you can leave to different implementations *what* to assemble (*what* car parts), whereas the base builder decides *how* to assemble them (car base before engine for instance).

Answer (score 0):

> Just my two cents on this :
>
> 1. Module1ServiceFactoryImpl seems to be implementing **singleton** pattern with all fields and constructor being private and
>      getInstance() being used to fetch a new instance of self.
> 2. It could have been a factory pattern if Module1ServiceFactoryImpl had implemented Module1ServiceFactory. The client code could then use
>      the factory impl as follows.

```
class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Module1ServiceFactory factory = Module1ServiceFactoryImpl.getInstance();
        ComponentA compA = factory.getComponentA();
        compA.printComponentA();

        ComponentB compB = factory.getComponentB();
        compB.printComponentB();
    }
}

class Module1ServiceFactoryImpl implements Module1ServiceFactory {
    private static Module1ServiceFactory instance;

    private Module1ServiceFactoryImpl() {
    }

    public static synchronized Module1ServiceFactory getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new Module1ServiceFactoryImpl();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public ComponentA getComponentA() {
        ComponentA componentA = new ComponentAImpl();
        ComponentB componentB = getComponentB();
        componentA.setComponentB(componentB);
        return componentA;
    }

    public ComponentB getComponentB() {
        return new ComponentBImpl();
    }
}

interface Module1ServiceFactory {
    ComponentA getComponentA();

    ComponentB getComponentB();
}

interface ComponentA {
    void setComponentB(ComponentB componentB);

    void printComponentA();
}

class ComponentAImpl implements ComponentA {
    ComponentB componentB;

    @Override
    public void setComponentB(ComponentB componentB) {
        this.componentB = componentB;
    }

    @Override
    public void printComponentA() {
        System.out.println("ComponentA");
    }
}

interface ComponentB {
    public void printComponentB();
}

class ComponentBImpl implements ComponentB {
    @Override
    public void printComponentB() {
        System.out.println("ComponentB");
    }
}
```